# Android : Button dependency on checkbox in Alert dialog

Tags: android, button, checkbox, dialog

I've an activity which starts with an alert dialog prompt. I have a checkbox of Don't show this again. I want the button to be
clickable after the Checkbox is
clicked, Thnx in advance, i hope my words make you understand what i am looking for. Here's my code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new     AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater adbInflater =     LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View eulaLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.note_for_layout, null);
    final CheckBox dontShowAgain = (CheckBox) eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.skip);

        adb.setCancelable(false); 
        adb.setView(eulaLayout);
        adb.setTitle("Warning!");
         adb.setMessage("");
  adb.setIcon(R.drawable.alert1);
    adb.setPositiveButton("Accept",     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void     onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   String checkBoxResult =     "NOT checked";
                    if (dontShowAgain.    isChecked())
                        checkBoxResult =     "checked";
                    String     PREFS_NAME = null;
                        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);

                editor.commit();

                    return;
            }
        }); 

        adb.setNegativeButton("Decline", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void     onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
                if (dontShowAgain.isChecked())
                    checkBoxResult = "checked";
                    String PREFS_NAME = null;
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
                // Commit the edits!
                editor.commit();
                    finish();
            }
        });
        String PREFS_NAME = null;
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");
    if (!skipMessage.equals("checked"))
        adb.show();

        super.onResume();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the button to be clickable AFTER the Checkbox is clicked?  If so, then you can do something like this:

```
final Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
positiveButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Then in your Checkbox add a listener:

```
dontShowAgain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked){
            // perform logic
            positiveButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I am getting an error here, what is `getButton`

     abd.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);  
   

wha

Comment: It won't work on AlertDialogBuilder i.e. your adb object.  Do this:

AlertDialog dialog = adb.show();

And then 

final Button positiveButton = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);

Comment: button remains unclickable after even after check box is checked. :(

Comment: Try OnClickListener instead:


checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    CheckBox cb = ((CheckBox) v);
    if (cb.isChecked()) {//enable your button here}
   }
  });

Comment: I will check on the OnCheckedChangeListener in the meantime.  I haven't used it in a while.  Had used OnClickListener instead.  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable the button using this code.

```
dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true/false);
```

Comment: So, do i need to set  `onClickListerner` to checkbox or what?

Comment: yes you have to set onClickListener and on onClick you have to check if the checkBox is checked or not.